# Highlighting/Selecting grid row in ExtJS

Tags: javascript, extjs, grid

I am newbie to Ext JS. I am working on a grid panel in which when I select/click any of the rows, then certain data related to the selected row is displayed in the panel below the grid. Also when the window is loaded the first should be selected/highlighted by  default. 
        Currently  the grid & panel is displayed properly. Even the data related to the selected row is displayed in the panel but the row is not getting highlighted. I have tried the `grid.focusRow(0)` & `grid.getRow(0).highlight()` methods but they are not working. Below is my code.

```
//the js file code
initComponent : function() { //within the window instance

    var single = false;
    var store = new Ext.data.XmlStore({//all necessary fields added}); //store
    HttpUtil.syncCall(this.url, "GET", this.loadStore, store,this);
    var acctTplMarkup = [//the fields here are displayed on row selection ];
                /*The template for displaying the details of the selected row */
                 this.acctTpl = new Ext.Template(acctTplMarkup);
    //check for request type, if type is range of checks create the grid
    if (single == false) {
        var gridView = new Ext.grid.GridView();
        var colModel = new Ext.grid.ColumnModel([ {
            header : 'Status',
            dataIndex : 'status'
        }, {
            header : 'Message',
            dataIndex : 'message'
        } ]);
        var selModel = new Ext.grid.RowSelectionModel({
            singleSelect : true
        });
        grid = new Ext.grid.GridPanel({
                                          ...
                        listeners : {
                render : function(grid) {
                    Ext.getCmp('check').store.on('load',function(store, records, options) { //check is the id value for the window instance
                         grid.getSelectionModel().selectFirstRow(); 
                    });
                }
            }
    }); //gridPanel
    } //if
    /* If request type is range select then display the grid  */
                ... 
    if (single == false) {
    grid.getSelectionModel().on('rowselect', function(sm, rowIdx, r) {
Ext.getCmp('check').acctTpl.overwrite(Ext.getCmp('detailPanel').body, r.data);
        }); //rowselect
    } //if

    Ext.apply(this, {
                                     ...
            listeners : {
            'afterrender' : function(){
            Ext.getCmp('check').acctTpl.overwrite(Ext.getCmp('detailPanel').body, this.store.getAt(0).data,true);
            }
        }
    });
    Check.superclass.initComponent.apply(this, arguments);

}, //initComponent
```

The data from the datastore is loaded & displayed properly but just the row is not highlighted. Can anyone tell me where I went wrong?

Answer (score 14):

There is no `getRow` method in `Ext.grid.GridPanel`. However, there is one in `Ext.grid.GridView`.

To highlight the row you should do the following:

```
var row = grid.getView().getRow(0); // Getting HtmlElement here
Ext.get(row).highlight(); // Getting element wrapper and using its "highlight" method
```

To perform row selection you are using grid's SelectionModel:

```
grid.getSelectionModel().selectRow(0)
```

Comment: Hey thanks for your response. I have already tried those methods but they are not working. My grid is complete but somehow I can't highlight the first row. Is there any other way?

Comment: Are you getting any errors with methods mentioned?
All the workarounds possible will bring you additional issues in future therefore you'd better try getting the existing way work before trying anything self-made.

Comment: `getView().getRow` doesn't exist in ExtJS 4; use `getView().getNode`.

Answer (score 6):

Component: **Ext.grid.Panel**

Version: **4.0.0**

To select one item and remove previous selection:

```
grid.getSelectionModel().select(0);
```

To select one item and keep previous selection:

```
grid.getSelectionModel().select(0, true);
```

Answer (score 1):

To select a row at a particular index, use the selection model.

```
Ext.grid.GridPanel.getView().getSelectionModel().select(index);
```

Answer (score 0):

In Sencha 7 you can select a particular row by grid.setSelection(item);

Ref https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.1/modern/Ext.grid.Grid.html#method-setSelection