# EXTJS Change default behaviour of the GridPanel row selection

Tags: extjs4, extjs4.1, gridpanel

I have a gridPanel based on EXT4. When I select a particular row, the row highlighting works based on the "id" given to the particular row. How do I change the default implementation to something to use like "rowId" instead of "id"
Where is this done? How do I make the change?

Comment: The question is unclear. Can you provide some code? What do you mean by 'select'? With the mouse, or using code?

Comment: just check. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8716873/highlighting-selecting-grid-row-in-extjs

Comment: @Izhaki - I mean a mouse select

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `idProperty` is the config option in `Ext.data.Model` which defaults to 'id'. You can change it to 'rowid' in your Model. If you are specifying fields directly in your Store, you will have to define a Data Model to have this option.

References:

http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.data.Model-cfg-idProperty
http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-cfg-fields